# Impedir que usuários façam conexão a lista do sharepoint usando o excel

Tags: lista, permissões, sharepoint

Tenho uma **lista no sharepoint** que utilizo para **inserir e editar** registros via **PowerApps**, e o **App controla** quais registros o usuário pode ter acesso.

Para **evitar que o usuário acesse** diretamente a lista no sharepoint e veja todos os registros (inclusive os que ele não pode e que o App filtra para ele), **configurei uma View** para isso, no entanto, **se o usuário for no Excel e criar uma conexão com o sharepoint, vai conseguir acessar a lista com todos os registros sem qualquer filtro.**

Como posso **evitar que o usuário realize esta conexão** com a base do sharepoint e veja todos os registros contidos?

Obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que você possa criar um nível de permissão que:
Impeça o usuário de ver páginas administrativas;
Impeça chamadas remotas;

Com isso você quebra a permissão da lista e atribui os usuários esse nível de permissão na lista.